# Writer outputs strange format to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have been trying to solve this issue for a few days now and can't seem to figure out how to get it done properly. Originally had a problem with printing entries to csv but thanks to SO that was solved quickly.

The problem is that when I print my xpath entries to csv the format becomes really weird and thus giving a lot of formatting issues when importing it to Excel or web. Printed format in CSV looks like this when opening or previewing it:

```
['something'] ['something\nblabla'] ['som&asddng\n2blas']
```

I purposely used `writerow(entries)` as I want the list to be in one row and each entry as a column. I have tried to use:

1. `writerows(zip(entries)` but the formatting of CSV is same.
2. `writerows(entries)` which gave me a correct formatting for each entry but obviously writes each entry as a new row.
3. using `re` but this only destroys the formatting when many rows are appended to the csv file (i.e. when the code is used in a for loop for multiple pages).

Thus I have two questions:

**1. Why is this formatting happening?**
**2. How can the formatting problem be solved!?**

I used the following code:

```
import csv
def get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath):
        return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]

File = open('list.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(File)
facts = [("//div[@class='left-col']/h6[2]"),
    ("//div[@class='left-col']"),
    ("//div[@class='left-col']/h6[1]"),
    ("//div[@class='left-col']/strong[1]"),
    ("//div[@class='left-col']/strong[2]"),
    ("//div[@class='left-col']//a[@rel='nofollow']")]
entries = []
for xpath in facts:
    entries.append(get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath))
print(entries)
writer.writerow(entries)
File.close()
```

Comment: What's your input file look like and desired output?

Comment: You're only writing one row to the CSV file. Was that intended? Usually `.writerow()` goes in a loop. Did you mean `.writerows()` ?

Comment: your `get_elements...` gives list and later you create list of lists. If you want it in one row then you should get elements from all lists and create one flat list. Maybe you should use `entries.extend()` instead of `entries.append()` or shortly `entries += get_elements_by_xpath()`. OR `get_elements...()` should return only one element, not list.

Comment: @RithinChalumuri The input comes from an URL which is password protected and in a foreign language but the output should basically be what the xpath elements are trying to grab (i.e. a title, description and URL).

Comment: @mario_sunny Yes, the writerow was intended as I don't want a list of values but rather a row of columns containing the values.

Comment: @furas Hm interesting, I will try this out! Will get back on this one

Comment: What's the format of your input file?

Comment: @RithinChalumuri input comes from a html file but furas example of extend worked perfectly!

Comment: @furas Thanks a lot, the `entries.extend()` worked exactly as described. Much appreciated and well explained. Kudos

Answer (score 1):

As user @furas suggested I tried applying `entries.extend()` instead of `entries.append()` and this turned out to work in terms of arranging the list of xpath entries into one row with each xpath entry being a column as well as a clean csv output.

See solution applied to code below:

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.example.com/list/')

File = open('list.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(File)

def get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath):
    return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]

facts = [("//div[@class='left-col']/h6[2]"),
    ("//div[@class='left-col']"),
    ("//div[@class='left-col']/h6[1]"),
    ("//div[@class='left-col']/strong[1]"),
    ("//div[@class='left-col']/strong[2]"),
    ("//div[@class='left-col']//a[@rel='nofollow']")]

entries = []
for xpath in facts:
    entries.extend(get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath)) # .extend instead of .append
writer.writerow(entries)
File.close()
```